# Calling a jQuery Function from within .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am uncertain why this code is not functioning. The goal is to hide an image and show another one in its place when the user clicks `.accent`. The currently displayed image (which is shown on page load) is referenced by the class `.ssi-hide`.

Here is the jQuery:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      // jQuery methods go here...

      var currentImage = '".ssi-hide"';

      $(".accent").click(function() {
         swapImage( currentImage, "#accent-img" );
      });
    }); //end jQuery
```

and here is the function:

```
    (function( $ ) {
        $.fn.swapImage = function( outPic, inPic ) {
            $( outPic ).fadeOut(200, function(){
            $( inPic ).fadeIn(400).css("display", "block").css("margin", "auto");
            });
            currentImage = inPic;
        };
    })( jQuery );
```

Chrome is notifying that: "Uncaught ReferenceError: swapImage is not defined"
as well as "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ".ssi-hide""

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: `$(this).swapImage(currentImage, "#accent-img");`

Comment: Thanks! That did away with the first browser error.

Comment: `$.fn.swapImage` really should be `$.swapImage` since you're not acutally using the instance your defining it on. then you call `$.swapImage` instead of  `$(this).swapImage`

Comment: also downvoter, why downvote? this question meets standards. it has all relevant code - properly formatted, is not subjective, and doesn't show a lack of research...

Comment: @TheRealMrCrowley, Thanks for mentioning the difference between $.fn.swapImage and $.swapImage. I had read it in a couple different sites when looking for an answer to this before I posted and it didn't make sense for some reason until I saw it worded that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `currentImage` doesn't need two sets of quotes, use `var currentImage = ".ssi-hide";` instead.

You're invoking the function as if it was a scoped function, but it's a jQuery plugin. instead of:

```
$(".accent").click(function() {
    swapImage( currentImage, "#accent-img" );
});
```

It ought to be:

```
$(".accent").click(function() {
    $(this).swapImage( currentImage, "#accent-img" );
});
```

But I don't see why you need to have it as a jQuery plugin since it doesn't use `this` anywhere.

Instead, it should really be defined as a class function

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.swapImage = function( outPic, inPic ) {
        $( outPic ).fadeOut(200, function(){
        $( inPic ).fadeIn(400).css("display", "block").css("margin", "auto");
        });
        currentImage = inPic;
    };
})( jQuery );
```

then you call

```
$(".accent").click(function() {
    $.swapImage( currentImage, "#accent-img" );
});
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the comment, that resolved one of the browser errors. Now I am left dealing with a syntax error pointing to ".ssi-hide" which I can't seem to understand.

Comment: @DominicFox that's because you'r double quoting it. you don't need the inner quotes in `currentImage`

Comment: @DominicFox than please mark this question as the correct one

Comment: *looking at the meta thread to figure out how to mark an answer as correct* I didn't forget, just a new user :D

Answer (score 0):

> Using onclick creates an attribute, and its value should be a string
>   that refers to a function, not an actual function. Using click creates
>   a property on the element, and its value should be the function
>   itself.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
          // jQuery methods go here...

          var currentImage = $(".ssi-hide");

          $(".accent").on("click",function() {
             $(this).swapImage( currentImage, "#accent-img" );
          });
        }); //end jQuery
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)